# Banging noise coming from somewhere every time when open or close the tap

Tags: plumbing

When open or close the tap in kitchen, bathroom or laundry knock or bang nose comes in every time. Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the water, open all the taps and connections (such as washing machine) and drain water from the pipes at the lowest point in the system that has a drain. Then close things up and turn the water back on. If you had "old fashioned water hammer arrestors" (just a vertical section of pipe) that will refill them with air, and might stop your problem.

If not, move on to adding some new-fangled ones. The air bubble is protected from slowly dissolving by a piston in the new type. Whether it's more or less reliable in the long run is an open question - in attempting solve one easily solved problem, considerable complexity has been added which may introduce new problems over time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new phenomena? You're describing "water hammer" and it's caused by a sudden pressure change causing the pipe to jump, basically. There are a few strategies but since you're saying multiple things cause it, start by making sure there's no place where a loose pipe can bang against other objects, such as wall framing.  In all likelihood you need a "water hammer arrester" installed (or replaced)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paul, a arrester should be installed.  If you can locate where the banging is and have access to the pipes if it's in a crawl space, you can put some straps on the pipes to make it more secure.